# Too many objects to separate UI, domain, and data layers

Tags: android, performance, domain-driven-design, mvp

I am designing my Android app to create model/entity classes separately for web service, database, domain, and UI.

I would be transforming my web service objects into domain objects. Then where I have recycler view, I create UI model objects for each row from my domain which would be a subset.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation

I have also come across https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/Clean-Contacts which is one sample codebase that strictly separates each layer.

I know it's a trade-off between performance and design, but what is recommended? I really like the design, but my concern is the number of objects instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is that it is fine to share entities between different layers of your application as long as doing so does not leak implementation details between the layers.

I would happily share a class such as:

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private boolean isInStock;

    //..
}
```

But would not share a class such as:

```
public class MyNetworkLibraryResponse<T> {

    private int status;
    private Throwable error;
    private T data;

    //...
}
```

If you ever decided to swap `MyNetworkLibrary` for `ShineyNewNetworkLibrary` you'd soon come unstuck.

`Product` however would be an integral part of your Domain.  Unless you have a need to re-use View code across business domains you'll likely be better off sharing it than causing increased complexity creating a `ProductViewModel`